# Comparison within a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have list of Data from a CSV file like this :

[image]

I wish to find a list of all members whose values lie within an interval. For ex. From the attached Dataset, to find list of all warriors whose `powerlevels` lie between 675000 and 750000.

In the following code I enter, the operators 'and', 'or', '&','|' are not working and are returning a `ValueError`.

```
strong = df[['name', 'attack', 'defense', 'HP','armour','powerlevel']][df.powerlevel > 675000 & df.powerlevel < 750000]
print(strong)
```

I get the following error-

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I get by this issue, without creating a different dataframe each time?

Comment: Please post `print(df)` instead of an image. It is much harder for others to reproduce :(

Comment: Try adding parenthesis `[(df.powerlevel > 675000) & (df.powerlevel < 750000)]`

Comment: you can use `loc`:

Comment: it seems your statement is interchanged. instead of this `strong = df[['name', 'attack', 'defense', 'HP','armour','powerlevel']][df.powerlevel > 675000 & df.powerlevel < 750000]` use `strong = df[[df.powerlevel > 675000 & df.powerlevel < 750000]]['name', 'attack', 'defense', 'HP','armour','powerlevel']`

Comment: Chris A, thanks for the answer. The parenthesis actually worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `loc`

```py
strong = df.loc[(df.powerlevel > 675000) & (df.powerlevel < 750000)]
strong = strong[['name', 'attack', 'defense', 'HP','armour','powerlevel']]
```